# Comparing Location.Hash to list contained in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I compare Window.Location.Hash to a list contained within an array to determine the 'current location'?

```
var exampleArray = ["#home", "#support", "#about"];
```

There are several other anchors on the page, but I only want those ones to change the 'current location' in the navigation pane.

Comment: [exampleArray.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would probably be to use `Array.prototype.indexOf` like so:

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    anchorList = ['#index', '#support'];

if( anchorList.indexOf( hash ) > -1 ){
  // anchor is in list, do your thing ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this only works in IE9 and up (and obviously Chrome, SF, FF). If you have to support IE8 (or even less), you can try a polyfill, a for loop or use http://underscorejs.org/ which has a `_.indexOf` helper.